# My method is exhausting heap space. Do I need to set something to null?

Tags: java, animation, javafx

I have created this method to display a list of images as a slideshow.
It works fine, until it has more than about 50 or 60 images to deal with.   Then it crashes, with

`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

So I'm wondering if I should be setting something to null each time round the loop?  I have searched here and around the web but haven't found the answer.

Here's the method:

```
private void createSlideshow(Stage stage, ArrayList<BufferedImage> slideList, int durationInSecs) throws InterruptedException {

            stage.show();
            SequentialTransition slideshow = new SequentialTransition();
            int i = 0;
            for (BufferedImage bi: slideList) {
                System.out.println(" Iteration " + (i++));
                ImageView slide = new ImageView(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null));    // LINE 108
                FadeTransition fadeIn =  new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(durationInSecs * 1000), slide);
                fadeIn.setFromValue(0.0);
                fadeIn.setToValue(1.0);

                PauseTransition stayOn = new PauseTransition(Duration.millis(durationInSecs * 1000));

                FadeTransition fadeOut =  new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(durationInSecs * 1000), slide);
                fadeOut.setFromValue(1.0);
                fadeOut.setToValue(0.0);

                SequentialTransition fadeInOut = new SequentialTransition();
                fadeInOut.getChildren().addAll(fadeIn, stayOn, fadeOut);
                slide.setOpacity(0.0);              
                root.getChildren().add(slide);            
                slideshow.getChildren().add(fadeInOut);
            }
            slideshow.play();
        }
```

The full runtime messages are as follows:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.createPlatformImage(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.scene.image.WritableImage.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(Unknown Source)
        at Slideshow.createSlideshow(Slideshow.java:108)
        at Slideshow.start(Slideshow.java:52)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$64/1581649247.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$49/1915503092.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$51/1557268138.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$50/1567581361.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$39/1645995473.run(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Exception running application Slideshow
```

Comment: Perhaps you don't enough heap for the images you are loading.  Note: when you do this the image is unpacked so will use it's full uncompressed size.  e.g. a 2 mega-pixel image might use 8 MB with 32-bit colour and if you have 60 of them this will use 1/2 GB.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Nearer to 1GB: there are two in-memory representations for each image in this implementation, one `BufferedImage` and one JavaFX `Image`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main `SequentialTransition` is loading all the images and retaining references to them before it starts to play. So this technique will not scale with the number of images (meaning that if you have enough images, it is guaranteed to exhaust your heap space).

If your images convert from `BufferedImage`s to FX `Image`s reasonably quickly, you can use a timeline to do this:

```
private void createSlideshow(Stage stage, ArrayList<BufferedImage> slideList, int durationInSecs) throws InterruptedException {

    stage.show();
    Timeline slideshow = new Timeline();

    ImageView slide = new ImageView();

    for (int i = 0; i < slideList.size(); i++) {
        BufferedImage bi = slideList.get(i);
        KeyFrame newImageFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationInSeconds * 3 * i), e -> 
            slide.setImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null)));

        KeyFrame startFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationInSeconds * 3 * i), 
            new KeyValue(slide.opacityProperty(), 0));

        KeyFrame endFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationsInSeconds * (3 * i + 1)), 
            new KeyValue(slide.opacityProperty(), 1));

        KeyFrame startFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationInSeconds * (3 * i + 2)), 
            new KeyValue(slide.opacityProperty(), 1));

        slideshow.getKeyFrames().addAll(newImageFrame, startFadeIn, endFadeIn, startFadeOut);

    }
    slideshow.play();
}
```

In this implementation, you create a timeline that has four key frames for each image. The first converts the current `BufferedImage` to a JavaFX `Image`, and the next one registered (which is at the same timepoint) sets the opacity to zero. The next key frame has the opacity set to 1 (so the timeline will interpolate the opacity between those two keyframes). The final key frame also has the opacity at 1, so it will be held constant for that portion of the timeline. On the next iteration of the loop, a new key frame is added with the opacity at 0, so the interpolation between the last key frame from one iteration and the key frame from the next iteration of the loop will create the fade out.

If the images take some time to convert, then this implementation may show some jerkiness due to a delay before the image appears, spoiling the "fade in" effect. A way around this is to use a background thread to convert the images and place them in a bound blocking queue:

```
private void createSlideshow(Stage stage, ArrayList<BufferedImage> slideList, int durationInSecs) throws InterruptedException {

    stage.show();

    int numImages = slideList.size();

    BlockingQueue<Image> images = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(3);

    Thread conversionThread = new Thread(() -> {
        for (BufferedImage bi : slideList) {
            try {
                images.put(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(bi, null));
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    });
    conversionThread.setDaemon(true);
    conversionThread.start();

    Timeline slideshow = new Timeline();

    ImageView slide = new ImageView();

    for (int i = 0; i < slideList.size(); i++) {

        KeyFrame newImageFrame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationInSeconds * 3 * i), e -> 
            slide.setImage(images.poll())); 

        KeyFrame startFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationInSeconds * 3 * i), 
            new KeyValue(slide.opacityProperty(), 0));

        KeyFrame endFadeIn = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationsInSeconds * (3 * i + 1)), 
            new KeyValue(slide.opacityProperty(), 1));

        KeyFrame startFadeOut = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(durationInSeconds * (3 * i + 2)), 
            new KeyValue(slide.opacityProperty(), 1));

        slideshow.getKeyFrames().addAll(newImageFrame, startFadeIn, endFadeIn, startFadeOut);

    }
    slideshow.play();
}
```

Finally note that your original code, and both of these implementations, expect a list of `BufferedImage`s to be passed to the method. This already consumes much memory: you are basically holding all the images in memory before you enter the method body. Depending on where these images are coming from, you may be able to, for example, pass a list of `File` objects and use the same techniques here to load each image on the fly as required (or create a small queue of them as in the second example). This will essentially scale to any number of images.

Comment: This answer provides a clearly set out explanation and solution.   It also helps me understand more about KeyFrames and TimeLines, and about passing bulky objects around.   Many thanks @James_D :)